# Java Atribute In Class and Subclass

Tags: java, class, attributes, subclass

I have the class Mappa with a subclass MappaFermi and an attribute mappaName (to choose from an Enum).

I am trying to write a test whith the constructor MappaFermi() but i can't seem to write it correctly.

```
public class Mappa {
    private Name mappaName;
    public Mappa (Name mappaName){
        this.mappaName=mappaName;
        ...

    }
}

public class MappaFermi extends Mappa {
    public MappaFermi(Name mappaName) {
        super(mappaName);
        }
    }

public enum Name {
 FERMI, GALILEI, GALVANI
}
```

I have tried all the suggestions given by eclipse but still get an error.

```
    public class MappaFermiTest {
        @Test
            public void testMappaFermi() {
                Mappa mappa = new MappaFermi(Name.FERMI);
                assertNotNull(mappa);
            }

 @Test
            public void testMappaFermi() {
                Mappa mappa = new MappaFermi();
                assertNotNull(mappa);
            }
    }
```

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: only the first test case should be compiled - but you have also 3 methods with the same name which also indicates a problem.

Comment: @user3707125 the constructor is undefined

Comment: @Zelldon no, i haven't written all of them at the same time, it's only to show what have i tried

Comment: Ok, so first case should probably work. Have you imported the enum and other Classes?

Comment: Are you the same guy? or you guys are working on the same assignment? Why is it MappaFermi again!

Comment: @Zelldon it doesn't, it says the constructor MappaFermi(Name) is undefined, yes i have imported all the classes

Comment: @Gosu It seems there are at least three of them. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `new MappaFermi()`, you have to define a no-argument constructor. This is the *default* constructor, and any class that has no other constructor will implicitly have a no-arg constructor. But as soon as you define a constructor with arguments, like `Mappa(Name mappaName)`, the no-arg default constructor is no longer available and has to be explicitly defined.

```
public MappaFermi() {
    super(null); // or whatever is a good 'default' name
}
```

Also, testing `assertNotNull(mappa);` right after `Mappa mappa = new MappaFermi(whatever);` is pretty pointless, as there is *no way* it could be `null` at this point.

Answer (score 0):

A few mistakes here:

-Three methods with the same name `testMappaFermi`.
The tests can be done all in one method, or you can rename the methods if you really want three methods.

-The second test is not written correctly. What would work:

```
Name mappaName = Name.FERMI;
Mappa mappa = new MappaFermi(mappaName);
```

-The third test uses `new MappaFermi()` without a no-argument constructor being defined.
Either you want to put an argument inside the constructor, or write a no-argument constructor as so :

```
public MappaFermi() {
    super(Name.FERMI);
}
```